# Bash Script with docker commands not running via Crontab

Tags: bash, docker

hey guys not sure what I am doing wrong here, but was hoping for some help.

I have a bash script with the following.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
docker exec -t wekan-db bash -c "scripts/wekandb_backup.sh" 
docker exec -t wekan-db bash -c "rm -r /dump/*; cp -r /mongodb_backup/ /dump/mongodb_backup"
docker cp wekan-db:/dump /home/ikadmin/codes/backup/wekan/$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
```

Everything executes correctly when I run the bash script from the terminal.

However when I try to run it via `crontab -e` it does not work. Logs do show crontab trying to run it.

Just in case the bash script is currently set as 777 as well.

Any help would be appreciated

EDIT: crontab command

```bash
19 8 * * * /bin/bash /home/ikadmin/codes/scripts/backup-wekan-docker.sh
```

Comment: Most likely because you have not provided the path to the docker binary.
https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it

Comment: Wow perfect thank you for that quick and easy answer